# installing redmine error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redmine, bluehost

I'm installing redmine and following instructions in their installation page.

when I run the command :  `bundle install --without development test`

I receive this error : Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /home1/twogupne (Errno::EACCES)
```

I'm on a bluehost server and I have noted that myhome directory is twohupne not twogupne (as written in the error )

any one can help ?

Comment: It seems like you are getting issue because you are not having permission to create folder. Please check the permission on the folder

Comment: this folder does not exists. it's wrong one

Comment: no one has permission to create it because I'm on a shared host bluehost. my root directory is home1/twohupne

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to modify your home's environment variable:

```
$ export HOME=/home1/twohupne
$ bundle install --without development test
```

If it doesn't work, have a look at [bundle-config](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html) and [bundle-install](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html)